# Password reset with devise fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting a very generic message when trying to recover password with devise (3.3.0):

> 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Reset password token is invalid

The log does not show any errors, it silently fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the code within User model?

Comment: I think it will helps you:

Delete the entire attr_accessible line in the User model

Explanation: Mass-assigned attributes are permitted by default in Rails 4 as part of it's strong parameters strategy -- you don't have to explicitly whitelist attributes in the model.

Comment: @EugeneTkachenko thanks for your help! I am running Rails 3.2.11 so unfortunately I can't get rid of attr_accessible yet. Here's what my User more looks like https://gist.github.com/andreitr/a58788362c782afd4745

Comment: BTW what the name of a row in db which responisible for password storing?

Comment: @EugeneTkachenko this is what my table looks like https://gist.github.com/andreitr/9befab09ebbf62c52ad0 The password is stored in encrypted_password field.